# Janrain field not getting updated

Tags: janrain

We have a Janrain implementation for user account management. I have added a new field `givenName` that is available in the schema, to a flow and to a form within that flow. I can see the field when I get details of it via `https://v1.api.eu.janrain.com/config/APPNAME/flows/FLOW/fields/givenName`.

But when I try to set a value to this field via a call to `oauth/update_profile_native` API, the field value is not getting set. I am using the correct `flow_version`. And I can see other fields like `gender` getting set correctly. thanks.

Comment: Without including your appname, client id,  and client secret perhaps if you post your curl call that might help.  Do you have any errors in your response from the server?  Also, make sure you are only using a client_id that has the "login_client" feature.  If the client_id is not a "login_client" then it will fail.  Docs: https://docs.janrain.com/api/registration/authentication/#oauth-update_profile_native .

Comment: I get a {"stat":"ok"} response. So, no errors.

Comment: After you modified your flow using the Configuration API did you update the flow version setting in your oauth call.

Comment: If the flow is modified then it gets a new flow version.  Referencing the old flow version would mean that the field you added gets ignored because the server only processes the form fields that are defined in the the specific flow version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. We discussed this with Janrain and were advised that the presence of a special widget-type field in the form was preventing the field from getting updated. The workaround was to attach a dummy value to this special widget-type field to ensure that the `givenName` field gets updated. Thanks